# Java, closing inline streams

Tags: java, stream

*Edit*: forgot to mention I'm using java 6

I was wondering about how to close resources in java.

See, I always have initialized streams like this:

```
ZipInputStream zin = null;

try {
    zin = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
    // Work with the entries...
    // Exception handling
} finally {
    if (zin!=null) { try {zin.close();} catch (IOException ignored) {} }
}
```

But, if an exception is thrown in `new ZipInputStream(...)`, would the opened streams in `new BufferedInputStream` and underliying `FileInputStream` be leaked?

If they are, what would be the most efficient way to ensure the resources are closed?, should I have to keep a reference to each `new ...Stream` and close them also in the `finally` block?, or should the final stream (`ZipInputStream` in this case) instantiated in some other way?.

Any comments are welcome.

Comment: Though the accepted answer is the one from @durandal, the answers from [aioobe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25892425/2468399) and [Thomas Stets](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25895296/2468399) give useful info or alternatives on how to prevent leaks from happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First lets take a look at what you have and what can go wrong with it:

```
try {
    zin = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
    // Work with the entries...
    // Exception handling
} finally {
    if (zin!=null) { try {zin.close();} catch (IOException ignored) {} }
}
```

a.) new FileInputStream() throws, zin will not be assigned. Nothing to close in this case. Ok.
b.) new BufferedInputStream() throws (possibly OutOfMemoryError), zin not assigned. Leaked FileInputStream(). Bad.
c.) new ZipInputStream() throws, zin will not be assigned. BufferedInputStream and FileInputStream to close. Closing either would be enough. Bad.

Whenever you *wrap* one stream into another, you are in danger of leaking the stream youre wrapping. You need to have a reference to it and close it somewhere.

A viable way top this is to declare a single InputStream variably to hold *the last create* stream (or in other words, the outermost of the nested streams):

```
InputStream input = null;
try {
    input = new FileInputStream(...);
    input = new BufferedInputStream(input);
    input = new ZipInputStream(input);
    ZipInputStream zin = (ZipInputStream) input;
    // work here
} finally {
     if (input != null)
         try { input.close(); } catch (IOException ignored) {}
}
```

This works, because if any of the `new *Stream()` throws, the variable `input` is still keeping track of the stream created before. The ugly cast from `input` to ZipInputStream is necessary, because you must declare `input` to be a type assignment compatible to all streams created.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
try (InputStream s1 = new FileInputStream("file");
     InputStream s2 = new BufferedInputStream(s1);
     ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(s2)) {
    // ...
} catch (IOException e) {
    // ...
}
```

Further reading: [The Java™ Tutorials: The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I'm using java 6 and don't have try-with-resources. Anyway I didn't know that existed so thanks!

Comment: Then I see no other way around it than to do as you suggest, to keep track of the "intermediate" streams and close them in a finally block.

Comment: @aioobe If the ZipInputStream threw in the constructor, wouldn't your example *still* leak the FileInputStream (zin would never be assigned).

Comment: That's a good point. I haven't read up on the spec, so I can't tell for sure. I've reformulated my answer into something that should take it into account.

Comment: @aioobe I have tried the tutorial, and I have to say they chose the worst possible example code; its deliciously unclear where it really counts. Thats *really* bad for a tutorial, and its the official one too...  I've checked the JLS, it seems the way you changed it is the correct one: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3

Comment: Thanks for sorting that out @Durandal! :-)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in this way:

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
try {
    ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(bis);
    try {
        zin = ;
        // Work with the entries...
        // Exception handling
    } finally {
        zin.close();
    }
} finally {
    bis.close();
}
```

And you can add error caching where you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an Exception in new ZipInputStream() or new BufferedInputStream() would leak the enclosed Streams, unless you do a cascading check in the exception handling:

```
FileInputStream fin = null;
BufferedInputStream bin = null;
ZipInputStream zin = null;

try {
    fin = new FileInputStream(file);
    bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin)
    zin = new ZipInputStream(bin);
    // Work with the entries...
    // Exception handling
} finally {
  try {
    if (zin!=null) {
       zin.close();
     } else if (bin != null) {
       bin.close();
     } else if (fin != null) {
       fin.close();
     }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // ignore
  }
}
```

However, since BufferedInputStream and ZipInputStream are mere wrapper around the FileInputStream the probability of an Exception is rather low. If at all, an Exception if most likely to happen once you start reading and processing data. And in that case zin is created, and a zin.close() will suffice.